# Flutter video isn't playing when called in initState method

Tags: dart, flutter

I have code to display a video, and it was working when I called that code, but when I put that same code inside the `void initState` method, it doesn't show the video on the app, but it plays the audio? Can anyone help me with what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call initState, your widget doesn't exist. So you can try fix it by starting video after build() method. To avoid re-creating widget inherit it from Stateless

Comment: Actually, my video player is playing in the build method. The code is just for initializing the video and I call `controller.play` if it wasn't clear before. Can you still help me with this?